# Cite URLs and papers in APA-style

Tags: citing, apa-style, url

I am writing a paper in `\documentclass[]{interact}`

Packages that I use for bibligraphy :

```
\usepackage[natbibapa,nodoi]{apacite}
\setlength\bibhang{12pt}
\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
```

I am not using numbers for citing the bibligraphies. My concerns are:

In case of papers, I use the usual way to cite a paper eg: `\citep{wang2017deep}` for the following item:

```
@inproceedings{wang2017deep,
  title={Deep model for dropout prediction in MOOCs},
  author={Wang, Wei and Yu, Han and Miao, Chunyan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 2nd International Conference on Crowd Science and Engineering},
  pages={26--32},
  year={2017},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

What I expect in my manuscript is : `Wang et al., 2017` but I get `W. Wang et al., 2017` in all its occurences. The worst thing is there is no consistency in citations some items appear(eg below) in the first format(`Author_lastname et al., year`) and some in the former.

E.g.:

```
 @inproceedings{chaplot2015predicting,
 title={Predicting Student Attrition in MOOCs using Sentiment Analysis and Neural Networks},
 author={Chaplot, Devendra Singh and Rhim, Eunhee and Kim, Jihie},
 booktitle={AIED Workshops},
 volume={53},
 pages={54--57},
 year={2015}}
```

Appears as `Chaplot et al.` everytime(except the first time).

Also whenever I cite some item for the first time I get it with all author names eg. first time I cite the above paper I got `W. Wang, Yu, & Miao, 2017`. I always wish to get just one format for all papers irrespective of their first or last usage i.e. `Author_lastname et al., year`.

Lastly I wanted to know about the cases of  URLs where I don't have author names e.g.:

```
@misc{class_central's_mooc_report_2019, title={Year of MOOC-based Degrees: A Review of MOOC Stats and Trends in 2018 - Class Central}, url={https://www.classcentral.com/report/moocs-stats-and-trends-2018/}, journal={Class Central's MOOC Report}, year={2019}, month={Mar}}
```

What is the best way to cite such URLs?

Comment: For the first problem, you need to make sure that the `.bib` items for identical authors have the same author names. So if you have `Wang, Wei` in one entry, and `Wang, W.` in another they will be treated as different. Furthermore, APA style requires initials in the case of identical author names, so if you have another `Wang` then initials will be used for both. Furthermore, APA style requires full authors (up to 5) in first mention. You can use `\shortcites` to force a short citation, but that would not be automatic (i.e., you'd need to make sure the actual first cite used that command.

Comment: If you just need an more generic Author/Year style, then you probably shouldn't use `apacite`. See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793) for some discussion.

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks for the comments! I understand your views and Latex's behavior appears more logical now. Do you have any idea about URLs? In case of no author details, my doc shows `titlename, year`. Is it the standard way?

Comment: The website in question ([`class_central's_mooc_report_2019`](https://www.classcentral.com/report/moocs-stats-and-trends-2018/)) appears to have an author: `author = {Dhawal Shah},`. Note that the `journal` field will probably be ignored for `@misc` entries.

Comment: @moewe There are others whose author name is missing eg `http://www.openculture.com/2013/04/the_big_problem_for_moocs_visualized.html` What about them?

Comment: If you can't even find a corporate author for those (like `author = {{Open Culture}},`) it is fine leaving the `author` field empty. If you still have a `year` and a `title` the output will usually (depending on your style) still be fairly sensible.